# XmlNode.SelectNode Weirdness (Not finding one of two very similar nodes)

Tags: xml, vb.net, csv, xmlnode

I ran into a bug with a piece of software I manage that is used to create Bills of Materials based on user selections.  It works with a large xml file that contains all of our part numbers as well as rules that we have written that are used to select those part numbers based on the selections that the engineers make.

I realized today that on one very specific part, around half of the selections work while the other half don't.  Here are the specifics.

We build a string based on the parameters of the rule in question, those parameters having been set based on the user selection.  This string is passed to the XmlNode.SelectNode method:

```
mItem = mXMLData.SelectNodes(XPath)
```

Here are two examples of the xpath string, one that finds a node and one that doesn't:

A)

```
/Root/Items/Item[@DropDownDescription='Ball Bearing' and @Diameter='1 7/16']
```

B)

```
/Root/Items/Item[@DropDownDescription='Ball Bearing' and @Diameter='1 11/16']
```

The first string, A, will not return any nodes, while the second string, B, will.  Here is the segment of our xml database that contains those part numbers:

```
<Item Key="FanBearing.1.3" ItemNumber="30400074" DropDownDescription="Ball Bearing" Diameter="1 7/16" />
<Item Key="FanBearing.1.4" ItemNumber="30400075" DropDownDescription="Ball Bearing" Diameter="1 11/16" />
```

(I removed some insignificant data from those entries, to make them shorter and easier to read here.  In both cases the data removed is near identical, with differences only being costs/weights, etc.)

As you can see, both entries, A and B, are in the data file.  The weirdest part is that I've been able to replicate the error with all of our different bearing sizes, and the ones that it does find have a double digit numerator in the fractional part of the number, and the ones that it doesn't find have a single digit numerator.  Now that of course has to be a coincidence since it is just a string and should not matter at all, but it has held true for every size we have.

That's all I've got, I've been going over this with one of our other developers (the one that actually wrote the bulk of this program) and we are both at a loss.  If anyone has any thoughts, please share.  Also, I tried to be as thorough as I could be here, but if there is any need for additional information, I would be happy to add it.

Thanks.

**EDIT:  I have figured it out, finally.**

Ok, so this ended up being a very weird thing that in the end wasn't related to the XmlNode.SelectNode function.

The XML file in question is compiled using a custom tool we created here from a collection of .csv files. The csv files make the data easier to manipulate when we need to make changes or things of that nature.

The tool that we have that compiles it also encrypts the file, as I mentioned earlier. We also have a version that will compile it without encryption which is how I was viewing it earlier.

When viewed unencrypted, the problematic line had one space in '1 7/16'

when the CSV file was viewed in notepad, there was one space.

when the CSV file was viewed in excel, it showed it with two spaces so that the columns matched up (excel formatting, ugh).

When I finally stepped through the code, and looked at the actual xml data in memory that it was searching on, the '1 7/16' had two spaces, so of course it never made a match.

In the end, I had to change the column of the CSV file in excel that held the diameter data to text format from number format, save it, and recompile. If I opened the CSV file again, changed nothing, and saved it, it would once again put the second space back in there.

I got it fixed though, and the program is working.

Thank you everyone for your responses (especially about the xpathvisualizer tool, very handy). This has been an exercise in frustration that burnt up my whole day.

Comment: Its almost certainly something thats not in your post thats breaking this- you could try XPath Visualizer Tool (http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/), and I did and both your A+B xpaths work correctly in it.

Comment: Sure enough, I used that tool and it found both xpaths just fine.  My only other thought is that the actual xml file that is used is encrypted when we compile it, and then unencrypted in the actual program.

Comment: Is it possible that the xpath API is attempting to perform a division when it encounters '/'?

Answer (score 0):

I have verified that a minimal example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(@"..\..\XMLFile1.xml");

            var x1 = doc.SelectSingleNode("Items/Item[@DropDownDescription='Ball Bearing' and @Diameter='1 7/16']");
            var x2 = doc.SelectSingleNode("Items/Item[@DropDownDescription='Ball Bearing' and @Diameter='1 11/16']");
        }
    }
}
```

...works for me in C# and .NET 4.0. I have excluded `<Root>` from my sample document since I cannot see how it could be relevant.

**edit #1:**

Likewise for VB, not that it should make any difference, and it doesn't. I also noticed that I used `SelectSingleNode` and not `SelectNodes` in my first example. I corrected this and it also worked as expected.